# Sort .Net Datatable on column with objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I'm trying to sort a DataTable where some columns may be a custom object. This object implements the `IComparable` interface.

```
Dim lView As DataView = lExport.DefaultView
lView.Sort = "ColA, ColB"
lExport = lView.ToTable()
```

ColB is an Object that implements `IComparable`.

```
Public Class DataLite
    Implements IComparable(Of DataLite)
    Public Property Value As Object
    Public Property Updated As Date?
    Public Property Options As Integer
    Public Property DataType As DataDefClass.DefDataType
    Public Property Format As String

    ' More fields and methods excluded 
End Class
```

When I set `lView.Sort = "ColA, ColB"`, I get an error - *Object Reference not set to an instance of an object*.

Some of the objects in the column may have a null value. How do I accomplish this?

**Edit**: Here is the IComparable implementation:

```
Public Function CompareTo(other As DataLite) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of DataLite).CompareTo
    If TypeOf (_Value) Is Date AndAlso TypeOf (other.Value) Is Date Then
        If CDate(_Value) < CDate(other.Value) Then Return -1
        If CDate(_Value) = CDate(other.Value) Then Return 0
        Return 1
    ElseIf Decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(_Value), Nothing) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(other.Value), Nothing) Then
        If CDec(_Value) < CDec(other.Value) Then Return -1
        If CDec(_Value) = CDec(other.Value) Then Return 0
        Return 1
    ElseIf _Value Is Nothing Then
        Return -1
    ElseIf other.Value Is Nothing Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return _Value.ToString.CompareTo(other.Value.ToString)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the implementation of the `IComparable(Of DataLite)` interface. I suspect that your comparison code assumes that both objects have a particular property set when they don't, e.g.`Format`. If you were to call `CompareTo` on a `Format` property that wasn't set then you would obviously get a `NullReferenceException`. You would need to write your comparison code to be tolerant of such situations.

Comment: By the way, when implementing `IComparable(Of T)`, it is considered good practice to implement `IComparable` too. It is considered good practice to always implement the non-generic version of an interface, if there is one, when implementing a generic interface. You would normally call the generic implementation from the non-generic one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  If the generic (object) Comparer is not implemented, the comparison wouldn't even be triggered by the Sort operation. As you said, the Comparer has to handle both null class objects and null class members. That's all to it. The DataView doesn't care.

Comment: Added the implementation of IComparable

Comment: As mentioned, you need `public Function CompareTo(object obj) As Integer` and test for `null` each object and object member you're comparing. The first test is of course `obj is DataLite`

Comment: If you had debugged your code then you should have been able to provide us with far more information and possibly even solved the issue yourself. I just used `Dim arr2 = {New DataLite With {.Value = Date.Today}, Nothing}` and then, when I sorted the array, I got a `NullReferenceException` on the line `If TypeOf (_Value) Is Date AndAlso TypeOf (other.Value) Is Date Then` because `other` was `Nothing`. No mystery about how that happened or why an exception was thrown.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the null check with `other.Value`. I've added that to the code and also implemented a generic IComparable as suggested by @Jimi . But that still doesn't solve the problem. I've tried setting breakpoints on the CompareTo methods, but it never reaches there. The exception triggers right at `lView.Sort = "ColA, ColB"` . If I only use ColA (which is a string type), it works fine. But sorting by ColB alone or along with ColA causes the error.

Comment: Okay! It turns out the method implementing `IComparable(Of DataLite)` is never called by the DataTable. Only the generic `Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo` is called. So I moved my code to the generic function is it runs beautifully. Thanks @Jimi and @jmcilhinney